# Factory-pattern for superclass and its subclasses

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have 3 classes which are one child of the other:
Class C ->(subclass of)-> class B ->(subclass of)-> class A.

Every class is real and I want to choose which one to instantiate by a method.
Can I use Factory-method and so factory-pattern to choose which class to create?

thank you.

Comment: Why would you not be autorize to ?^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use factory method pattern with covarient return types. Here's a sample code.

```
public class MazeGame {

    public Maze createMaze() {
        // build the maze here.

        return aMaze;
    }

    public Room makeRoom(final int number) {
        return new Room(number);
    }

    public Wall makeWall() {
        return new Wall();
    }

    // ...
}


public class BombedMazeGame extends MazeGame {

    @Override
    public Room makeRoom(int number) {
        return new RoomWithABomb(number);
    }

    @Override
    public Wall makeWall() {
        return new BombedWall();
    }

}
```

Comment: tank you, I even saw this example in Wikipedia. I ask you another detail: for populating new instances I would use patterns (if neeed). Can I create a strategy pattern for (databaseLoad vs userCreate) the instance attributes and put them into new instance? (tank you)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. However `Strategy` is a behavioral pattern and has nothing to do with creating objects. Use `Strategy` only if you need to encapsulate algorithms as objects. Contrary `Factory Method` is a creational pattern. I got the sample code above from the Gang of Four Design Patterns book which is one of my favorites.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the factory method is the way to go in your context. I've provided quick example how to implement it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactoryMethodExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a letter A, B or C: ");
    String input = reader.nextLine();
    Factory factory = new ConcreteFactory();
    A myClass = factory.getClass(input.charAt(0));
    if(myClass != null)
    {
        myClass.print();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Wrong input");
    }
  }
}

class A
{
  public void print()
  {
    System.out.print("I'm class A");
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  @Override
  public void print()
  {
    System.out.print("I'm class B");
  }
}

class C extends B
{
  @Override
  public void print()
  {
    System.out.print("I'm class C");
  }
}

abstract class Factory
{
    public abstract A getClass(Character letter);
}

class ConcreteFactory extends Factory
{
    @Override
    public A getClass(Character letter)
    {
        if(letter.equals('A'))
        {
            return new A();
        } 
        else if(letter.equals('B'))
        {
            return new B();
        }
        else if(letter.equals('C'))
        {
            return new C();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```